# Где в андроид студии устанавливать Target sdk

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest

Где в андроид студии устанавливать targetSdkVersion и minSdkVersion. В манифесте не устанавливается почемуто

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это надо устанавливать в `build.gradle (module app)`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
```

Comment: ок. посмотрю...